# Error naming the class

Tags: class, templates

I have this code (snippet):

```
for (itr = GameObjectList.begin(); itr != GameObjectList.end(); ++itr)
{
    if ((*itr)->GetComponent<Light>() && (*itr)->GetComponent<Light>()->GetEnable())
    {
           (*itr)->GetComponent<Light>()->Render();
   }

}
```

Error in line 3 and line 5. The reason, the name "Light" which is a Component of my engine, if I change the name of the class Light to any other name (example "Light2") it works!

the GetComponent template function is:

```
template <typename T>
T* GetComponent()
{
     for(itr = CompList.begin() ; itr != CompList.end() ; ++itr)
    {

        if (T* type = dynamic_cast<T*>(*itr))
        {
            return type;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
};
```

what the f#%k is happening? maybe a file corruption, with my cpp files? i don't know

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
    error: no matching function for call to 'GameObject::GetComponent()'
```

Comment: What's your error message?

Comment: You need to show more code, e.g. the whole function the first code snippet is in.

Comment: there is no more code because it works fine with any other name, only with "Light" fails

Comment: I suppose you compile with GCC (error message looks like that). If so, there should be more information about the error, e.g. "candidates are:" and the list of function overloads tried to call. Could you please provide this information?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error! In the GameObject class a have an enum with the type of the gameObject, one of the element was "Light" , and that enum was global. The solution is to make the enum public.